# Platform Encryption Implications on Data Import/ Export

Tags: security, import, encryption, partner, platform-encryption

I read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_considerations_general.htm) that "You can’t use the Data Import Wizard to perform matching using master-detail relationships or update records that contain encrypted fields. You can use it to add new records, however."

However, I was able to update a managed custom object that has encrypted custom fields (by matching an unencrypted field). Can someone please clarify what the document means?

Comment: Are you sure that the field was encrypted by Shield Platform and wasn't a standard encrypted field?

Comment: Yes. We enabled SHIELD for managed packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for raising this issue, the documentation is certainly confusing.

Essentially, when a field is encrypted you should not be able to filter on it in the data import wizard as in other areas.

We're talking with our doc writers to have the official documentation updated.